# Windows Universal App UI Library Parser internal error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, win-universal-app

I built a user control in an user control library and I want to include it into my windows universal app.  I remember in the old days you had to add something to app.xaml (something like pack:// this is my xaml).

So my thoughts (or hope) I just include my library and user the control.  When I do I get - Parser internal error: Object writer 'xClassNotDerivedFromElement'.

I tried adding it as a msappx reference in the App.Xaml, but I may have the syntax wrong.  If I can get this working by literally copying over the code itself into my project (which I do not want to do).  Suggestions?
Thanks

EDIT: Added source code

```
public MainPage()
{
    _webControl = new NativeWebView.WebUserControl();
    _webControl.Loaded += _webControl_Loaded;
    _contentView = new NativeWebView.ContentView(_webControl);
    this.InitializeComponent();
    root.Children.Add(_webControl);
}


public sealed partial class WebUserControl : UserControl, IWebView
{
    public WebUserControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found out the answer.  So to include a library into another project, you have to have some extra crazy files (.xr.xml and .xrc).  I manually copied them into a folder, but it seems they can get out of date.  I found that if I want to include the library from the build directory, I have to check a box in the build properties page (Generate library layout).  This copies the files for me.  SOLUTION!

Answer (score 0):

Just add namespace of the library into root tag of the page where you use the control, ex. for ImageButton control in WinRT XAML Toolkit:

```
<Page
[...]
xmlns:toolkit="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls">
```

[...]

```
<toolkit:ImageButton [...] />
```

[...]

If you still get xClassNotDerivedFromElement, it means there's a problem in the library. (need source to track it)